# How to run migrations in Laravel project with waavi/translation?

Tags: laravel, artisan-migrate

I have a Laravel project with `waavi/translation` module. My DB is fresh and doesn't have any tables. I'm trying to execute migrations

```
php artisan migrate
```

But I get an error message:

```
In Connection.php line 712:
                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'abc.ai_translator_translations' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `ai_translator_translations` where `locale` = pl and `namespa  
  ce` = * and `group` = *)                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                 

In Exception.php line 18:
                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'abc.ai_translator_translations' doesn't exist  
                                                                                                               

In PDOConnection.php line 82:
                                                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'abc.ai_translator_translations' doesn't exist
```

But when I try to run migrations only from this module:

```
php artisan migrate --path=./modules/translation/database/migrations
```

I get the same error...

I can't execute migrations from this module, because I don't have executed migrations from this module

How can I solve that?

Comment: use --step option of migrate command "php artisan migrate --step=1" once and next run "php artisan migrate --path=./modules/translation/database/migrations". This option will run only one migration at a time, allowing you to troubleshoot any issues with specific migration files. and make sure setting of your database credentials in your .env file.

Comment: Turns out I can't even execute `php artisan` because I got the same error

Comment: so you have something getting in the middle of the initialization and is trying to execute something... try running `php artisan -vvv` for a better output

Comment: There's exactly the same output. Without any additional information